# How do I correctly use variables in the POST request in Jenkins Slave

Tags: jenkins, post, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

Here is my POST request.

```
curl -v -k -H "Content-Type:application/json" -b /tmp/zen.cookies -X POST https://${WEB_URL}/zen-data/v2/serviceInstance -d 
{"serviceInstanceNamespace":"${namespace}","serviceInstanceVersion":"1.3.5","createArguments":{"parameters":{"global.icp4Data":"true","global.pvc.pvProvisioning":"NamedStorageClass","global.filebeat.output.logstashEnabled":"false","global.filebeat.output.consoleEnabled":"true","metadata.storageClass":\\"${storageclass}\\","imagePullSecrets":"ownerServiceInstanceUsername":""},"transientFields":{}}
```

It gives me this error:

```
{"code":400,"message":"parsing body body from \"\" failed, because invalid character 's' looking for beginning of value"}* Could not resolve host: serviceInstanceDisplayName; Unknown error
12:24:32 * Closing connection 1
12:24:32 curl: (6) Could not resolve host: serviceInstanceDisplayName; Unknown error
12:24:33 * Could not resolve host: serviceInstanceNamespace; Unknown error
```

Comment: Things are missing here `"imagePullSecrets":"ownerServiceInstanceUsername":""`. Perhaps a value for the key `imagePullSecrets`.

Comment: Good observation, but no. 
If I hard-code the variables. It works just fine. I can assure you that everything is fine with imagePullSecrets.
Please consider looking only at the variable substitution.

Comment: Another observation - you have escaped `${storageClass}` but not `${namespace}`. Likely you do not want the former to be interpolated immediately while making the request? But then looking at the error, it appears that `\\"${storageclass}\\"` is not a valid JSON syntax as the value in its entirety must be within double quotes. The program rather sees it beginning with a `\\` and complains?

Comment: Also, what I can gather from online search is that JSON does not support variables natively - https://stackoverflow.com/a/23870176/8895640. But there are workarounds which may or may not apply to you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/48957641/8895640.

Comment: Thanks Dibakar! I will try out the suggestion in this link stackoverflow.com/a/48957641/8895640

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To substitute a variable inside JSON in POST command, you need to do this:

```
"'"${variableName}"'"
```

A double quote inside a single quote which is inside a double quote.
So it looks like this:

```
 curl -X POST www.example.com -d '{"country": "city","province":"'"${variableName}"'"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it looks like you missed one bracket, Try to add `}` in the end.

Regarding Parameter in json format use only `"$storageclass"`. or something like this :

```
json="{\"name\": \"$name\", \"text\": \"$Text\"}"
```

Comment: Thanks Akriti! 
I tried using \\ but didn't tried using \. 
I will try that.